# WP Super Cache Bug with Ubermenu

Tags: cache

Im having a serious issue with WP Super cache and UberMenu. For some reason, every now and again, I will view my site, and it will have the default styling applied to ubermenu and then this unstyled version gets stuck in the cache and stays until I clear it.

I clear the cache, and my custom styling from my main stylesheet gets applied and everything is fine for a while. If i turn off caching, its fine. Any ideas what issue may be causing this?

Is there a way to exclude the CSS for the ubermenu from supercache?

Thanks
Andy

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced the same issue. I'm not 100% sure yet if this is helping because it's an intermittent issue, but as noted on the plugin author's docs, this is a potential new fix for the problem:

```
<!-- mfunc wp_nav_menu( $args ); -->
<?php wp_nav_menu( $args ); ?>
<!-- /mfunc -->
```

**UPDATE**

As of version 2.3 of uberMenu, there is a fix the plugin developer created that I've found to work better.

`<?php if( function_exists( 'uberMenu_direct' ) ) uberMenu_direct( 'primary' ); ?>`

Note: *primary* is the theme location handle/ID/slug of your WP menu / uberMenu.

Source: http://sevenspark.com/docs/ubermenu-caching

Comment: Maybe I'm missing smth obvious, but where exactly did you add this code as in my set up I have no custom function that adds the menu, Ubermenu does all the calls.

Comment: @IntricatePixels - Sorry, I should have provided more information. mfunc is supposed to basically keep whatever function that is wrapped within it dynamic. So this code example would go wherever in your theme (header.php maybe) that you call `wp_nav_menu()`. For more details check out the WP Super Cache FAQ -> http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/faq/